# how do I get of the particular Jbutton clicked?

Tags: java, swing

I have a list of titles for which I am making Jbuttons. I want that when I click a particular button I get that text.I searched on net and tried some things but they are giving random title out of the list and not the one on which I click. Please let me know where I am making mistake. Any kind of help will be highly appreciated. Thanks,

```
           for(String title:listOfTitles){
           button1.setText(title);
           button1.setBounds(20,50,100,25);
           button1.setBorderPainted(true);
           button1.setFocusPainted(true);
           button1.setContentAreaFilled(false);
           button1.setOpaque(false);
           button1.setBackground(Color.lightGray);
           button1.setBounds(5,i,100,100);
           button1.addMouseListener(new java.awt.event.MouseAdapter() {
                public void mouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {
                jTextField3.setText(((button1) evt.getSource()).getText());
            }

         });
         jPanel3.add(button1);
         jPanel3.revalidate();
         jPanel3.repaint();
         i = i+15;
     }
```

Comment: *"I have a list of titles.."*  The appropriate component would probably be a [`JList`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JList.html).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In general, you do not want to add a MouseListener to JButtons. If you've gone through the button tutorials, surely you've seen that you should use ActionListeners instead. If you do this, call `getActionCommand()` on the ActionEvent object passed into the listener's `actionPerformed(...)` method and you'll get the String you want.

i.e.,

```
myButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
   actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
      System.out.println("Button's actionCommand: " + evt.getActionCommand());
   }
});
```

Legal Disclaimer: This code has not been compiled nor tested and is not meant to be a copy and paste solution, but rather to give you an idea of how ActionListeners work, so you can adapt the concept to your program.

Also, please check out the [Swing JButton tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/button.html) for all the rest of the details that you'll need to know.

Comment: I am new to java and will highly appreciate if you give me some code.thanks

Comment: I tried this and unsupprted exception appears and random title is generated: button1.setActionCommand(button1.getText());           
    button1.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    String ac = e.getActionCommand();
                    System.out.println("Button's actioncommand:" + ac);
                    throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet.");
                }
                
                });

Comment: @user127: You won't want to post code in comments since they cannot be formatted and become unreadable. Better to edit your original question and post your new code and question in there, and then notify us of the change in a comment.

Comment: @user127: You really shouldn't be surprised that an UnsupportedOperationException occurs, because your method is throwing one. Get rid of that line of code.